# Google recaptcha public and private key

Tags: c#, asp.net, recaptcha

We are using google recaptcha in one of our projects. To get the private and public key for captcha we just used the url as http://localhost:4345/. Can the same private and public key be used in live site also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that's perfectly ok to use the same key pair for both local testing and server deployment (as long as you keep your private key a secret). On the other hand, if you did not select the "global key" option, the keys are unique to your domain and sub-domains (event though all keys will again work on localhost without any problem).

Comment: @Teoman: Keeping secret means? Since we are giving the private and public key in .aspx page anyone can access it by taking the page source. am i right?

Comment: You just hand out the public key, private key resides on your .aspx file or the database but not served to the client browsers. If you're server wasn't breached, your private key is safe, don't worry.

Comment: @Teoman: Yes i checked the option  "Enable this key on all domains (global key)"

Comment: @mahesh, then you're good to go. Your keys are available for any domain you want. I personally use same pair of keys at 3 of my seperate web sites + at my home computer at localhost:80 for testing purposes. They all work very well.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

When you generate a key for the recaptcha, if you check the checkbox to generate it globally, it will work. See in the image

Comment: This answer and screen shot are obsolete, the global option is gone. You can however provide a list of domains, not just one, but contrary to the documentation, leaving it blank and disabling Domain Name Validation doesn't appear to work.

Comment: My apologies to the answerers, after some research it appears that while my comment is correct, for today, my downvote is not the accepted way of handling an obsolete answer. I didn't want to change that to an upvote -- "This answer is useful" -- because currently it's not, so I guess we're stuck with the situation as it is.